# Riley Riddle with a little bit of ciphering

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, cipher, affix-riddle

> The prefix is a hook, but I removed one part... But it is also locked, and I forgot the key.
>
> (Just to share with you all, I am eating a salad with a raspberry vinaigrette.)
>
> The infix is my favorite numbers, which are: 1, 19, 20, 18 and 15.
>
> The suffix is like the first letter of the prefix. You just need to circle around your house to find the correct answer...
>
> (After finding the correct answer, you must take note that it sounds like that letter, but you should not take it literally. It may be a different spelling but still sounds alike.)

**What word I am looking for???**

Hint 1:

> The prefix is the word 'hook', but with something done to it...

Hint 2:

> Remove one letter from the word 'hook'.

Comment: 1 19 20 18 15 is the letters of the alphabet and it spells astro

Comment: Are the question marks added in the last edit a clue?

Comment: @noedne no I just edited it so it goes up 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the word:

> catastrophe?

By taking

> HOK and passing it through a vigenere cipher with the key FORGOT, you get CAT.

Putting this together with

> ASTRO, from your infix and the suffix 'PHE'(You can get the letter 'P' by doing a ROT13 on the letter C[first letter of prefix]).

Comment: The suffix part is still wrong, using vigenere cipher is wrong. Look at the clue in the prefix, answer it correctly and the +50 rep is all yours

Comment: Is it that if you do a ROT13 on the letter C, you get P, which sounds like PHE?

Comment: yes that's it please update the answer

Comment: Done! Nice riddle :)